# What are the TestCafe requirements for the HTML and Javascript used in a WebApp (i.e a Tomcat web app)

Tags: javascript, testing, dynamic, testcafe, requirements

The TestCafe docs lack any but the simplest requirements.

The web app i wrote in 2008-9 is XHMTL 1.0 syntax generated by
Freemarker templates under SpringFramework 2.5.x, that have lots
of forms and pages with excel like tables full of buttons,links,form+input, etc
in each row of the tables.

It uses a `onclick="..."` javascript for conditional button behaviors
that do input validation on the form inputs, and other such, alert()s, etc.
I used css / class attribute only for formatting, but lots of `id="xxx"`
and `getElementById("xxx")` in the javascript and update the DOM from .js
functions.  I did not user any javascript frameworks like Node.js or jquery.
I did use iFrames for printout frames.

I also have a few cases of Select menu B options map is dependent on a
Select Menu A choice, which causes dynamic replacement of the menu B options map.
The app has more than 150 unique pages, 5 user roles. The app works in Firefox,
Safari and IE11/Edge, Chrome.

Q: Can TestCafe test a WebApp implemented in this outdated manner?

Q: Can it handle the dynamic DOM modification made via javascript functions
invoked by `onclick=" func()" and onselect=" func()"` of button and select tags?

Q Can TestCafe `Selector()` use element ids to `find()` elements?
as the web app generates unique ids for link, button, input, etc, tags
in rows of the tables via freemarker template variables.

Answer (score 1):

At present, TestCafe may have issues during testing of XHMTL pages (see [this page](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/350) for more information). I am not familiar with the Tomcat Web application. However, if this web application can be opened in a browser, TestCafe can operate with it.

Answer (score 1):

Q1) I don't have any insight on this question.

Q2) Yes. Look into async, await, and promises.

Q3) Yes. Any kind of attribute. You mentioned find() specifically, so look into: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402750/reference/test-api/selector/find